# implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long' in c using keil

Tags: c, stm32, keil

I'm new in the programingo of STM32, I've whatched aome tutorials, but whe I've put in practice the last, keil give me some warnings (the tutorial is about of GPIO INPUT OUTPUT LIBRARY FROM SCRATCH).
the warnigs are:

```
gpi_drive.c(35): warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-conversion]
        *CR |= ((dir<<(pin*4)) | (opt<<(pin*4+2)));
            ~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gpi_drive.c(34): warning: variable 'CR' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
        *CR &= ~(0xfu<<(pin)*4); /*Reset the target pin*/
         ^~
gpi_drive.c(7): note: initialize the variable 'CR' to silence this warning
```

```
    volatile unsigned long * CR;

#include "gpi_drive.h"



void init_GP(unsigned short port, unsigned short pin, unsigned short dir, unsigned short opt)
{
volatile unsigned long * CR;
unsigned short offset = 0x00;

if (pin > 7)
{
    pin -=8;
    offset = 0x01;
}

if (port == 1)
{
    RCC_APB2ENR |= 4;  /*Enabling port A*/
    CR = (volatile unsigned long *) (&GPIO_A + offset);
}

if (port == 2)
{
    RCC_APB2ENR |= 8;  /*Enabling port B*/
    CR = (volatile unsigned long *) (&GPIO_B + offset);
}

if (port == 3)
{
    RCC_APB2ENR |= 0x10;  /*Enabling port C*/
    CR = (volatile unsigned long *) (&GPIO_C + offset);
}

*CR &= ~(0xfu<<(pin)*4); /*Reset the target pin*/ //this is the line 34
*CR |= ((dir<<(pin*4u)) | (opt<<(pin*4+2)));      //this is the line 35



}
```

This is the code that I have, I don't know how to make that the numbers of the rows appears, sorry for this. And if you need more information let know, and thak you so much

Comment: In line 35 the `unsigned short`s are implicitly promoted to `int` for the bit manipulations, and then again implicity converted to `unsigned long`. Suggest casting `(unsigned long)dir` and `(unsigned long)opt`.

Comment: unless there are high-order bits shifted into bits 32-63 which you specifically want to be `0` in which case just cast as `(unsigned int)`. The value of `pin` isn't stated.

Comment: thak you i put unsigned long and the warning is fix, but i don't underatand if i declared the parametter as unsigned short and now becomes an unsigned long, is it affect in some way?

Comment: and in the line 34 continue give me this warning "warning: variable 'CR' may be uninitialized when used here"

Comment: The uninitialized warning is because `CR` is only assigned when `port` has certain values.

Comment: See [Integer promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) and [Shift operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Shift_operators).